# Missing something about how a function works? (at least for JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setTextState] = useState("Press the button!");

  // this is the variable I want to output incremented by 1 
  // each time the button has been pressed
  let i = 0; 
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{state}</Text>
      <Button 
        onPress={() => setTextState(`The button has been pressed ${++i} time(s)`)} 
        title={"Button 1"}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The outputs sequence is something like this:

initial - The button has been pressed 0 time(s)

1 - The button has been pressed 1 time(s)

2 - The button has been pressed 2 time(s)

3 - The button has been pressed 1 time(s)

4 - The button has been pressed 2 time(s)

If the function really cannot contain variable outside of his "state", how come the {i} variable still is reachable and incremented (twice-only, but still incremented).

Comment: It keeps a reference to the `i` variable via a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It rerenders the state because `setTextState()` is invoked, which is defined as a function that sets a piece of state and rerenders the component

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `i` as you did (as explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59864618/missing-something-about-how-a-function-works-at-least-for-javascript#comment105860634_59864618)). You might want to look into the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook for future reference as it's a good way to have persist variable throughout the lifetime of your component.

However, based on the example you provided, I'd highly recommend that you just use the state:

```
function App() {
  const [buttonCount, setButtonCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>The button has been pressed {buttonCount} time(s)</Text>
      <Button 
        onPress={() => setButtonCount(prevButtonCount => prevButtonCount + 1)} 
        title={"Button 1"}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```